# Why does my Firebase request return as 500 (internal server error)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following code that does not execute (I get back 500 internal server error).

What did I do wrong?

```
app.post('/api/sign-in', function (req, res, next) {
    //auth
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.query.username, req.query.password)
        //get back promise, log user object's email address
        .then(function (user) {
            console.log(user.email)
        })
        //log error
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
});
```

Comment: can you post your console.log(error) output?

Comment: there is no output. npm start does not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose as you are using a ***post*** request then you have to use `req.body` instead:

```
req.body.username, req.body.password
```

Comment: I fixed it. But I still get the 'unhandled error' error.